# PHP upload file and read line by line

Tags: php, html

I've got a really bizarre problem here. I'm using the code below to upload a txt file to my server via php.

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php" method="POST">
        <input type="file" name="uploadfile">
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

After uploading the file (which works fine) I convert the contents into an array via the following code:

```
$fp = @fopen($file, 'r'); 

if ($fp) { 
    $domains = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize($file))); 
}
```

Then I run a preg_match to filter down the array:

```
$list = preg_grep('/^[a-z]+\.com$/', $domains);
```

I confirmed that $domains is getting populated with the data in the txt file, however when I run print_r($list) it's only returning "array( )"

When I upload the same exact text file with FTP and run print_r($list) it works fine.

I also noticed when I upload the same text file with my FTP client the filesize of "domains.txt" is smaller than when I upload it using my html form. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: please dont ignore the warning solve them .

Comment: file() would provide a line by line array, more efficient than your use of freed and explode

Comment: @user1647347 If you liked my answer, you can accept it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may have to do with line endings being automatically changed between UNIX and Windows by your FTP client.

To resolve this, just use `trim` to cleanse every line before using `preg_grep`. Something like:

```
foreach ($domains as $key => $domain) {
    $domains[$key] = trim($domain);
}

// or better use array_walk and closures PHP 5.3+
array_walk($domains, function(&$e) { $e = trim($e); });
```

The problem would be because your regular expression has explicit start-of-line and end-of-line anchors.

BTW you could load up the whole file into an array of lines in one statement by just using the `file` function.

```
$domains = file($file);
```

Comment: i would bet a dollar that's the issue

Comment: Worked...someone owes Dagon a dollar.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Dagon haha, the dollar is precisely the issue :D